# How you manage the output values is a string in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, django-views

In my Django backend db, results are stored in result column, and result itself looks like this:

```
result = [
{"pod_name": "kafka-9", "resolution_ms": 60000,"value": 420.85}, 
{"pod_name": "kafka-3", "resolution_ms": 60000, "value": 418.0},
...
]
```

When I do the get_results from the filter

```
results = DjangoCeleryResultsTaskresult.objects.filter(task_id=taskname).values('result')
just_res = list(results)[0].values()
```

just_res is a dictionary values that converted my original list as one giant string

```
dict_values(['[{"pod_name": "kafka-9", "resolution_ms": 60000, "value": 420.85}, {"pod_name": "kafka-3", "resolution_ms": 60000, "value": 418.0}]'])
```

However, I want my just_res is a list of nested dictionary, like it is stored in db.

I tried:

```
service_results = list(just_res)[0]
```

but this only convert me a string, and convert that string to a list is another nightmare, cannot just use list() method.

Can you help me figure out either?

1. convert the values of string(**just_res**) into a list?

or

2. A way to pull django results as a list from db?

In all, not sure why django filter objects values(), I can only get results as a string, not the original datatype. Am I using it wrong or another other approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what field you use in Model for result. Also show what you expect finally.

Comment: The result is the column I pasted at the top, I just want the same result, return the result list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks, you have a models.JSONField() where you storing your required data. Getting this data from an API as a `list of dictionaries` is pretty straight forward. You mentioned a `list of nested dictionaries` but in the column `result`, you have no `nested dictionary`, not that its any different in getting it in an API response.

If you are using `rest_framework` then all you need is a `model serializer`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DjangoCeleryResultsTaskresult #import this model
        fields = ["result"]
```

Now, inside your view, use the above serializer. There is no need to use `values`, `list` and so on. The serializer elegantly takes care of everything.

```
return Response(
    ResultSerializer(DjangoCeleryResultsTaskresult.objects.filter(
           task_id=taskname), many=True).data
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is truly something I did not think of and pretty elegant.  My use case requires me to trim the results and then publish to views. which is why I want to get the result content as a <list> type. Any idea, what is the datatype from sealizer().data?

Comment: I tried it, it is just return a json response, which is not what I wanted

Comment: @JamesXu didn't know you that you don't even want a response object & want only a single list, which I must say is quite rare with an API. Anyways I have updated the response structure to only return the required list.

Comment: Yeah. I would not return as it is, since I would need to manipulate data then return it to view.  I did figure it out using this, since, the results was a text not a proper datastructure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954186/convert-a-string-of-list-into-a-list...